# Dask SVD Computation and Reuse of Intermediate Values

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I have an enormous, multi-gigabyte matrix in a Dask array.  If I do the following:

```
usv = dask.array.linalg.svd(A)
```

Followed by

```
u.compute()
s.compute()
v.compute()
```

Can I ensure Dask will reuse the intermediate values of the process, or will the whole thing be rerun for u, s, and v?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you've written it will not reuse any intermediate values (unless, perhaps, you're using the [distributed scheduler](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/memory.html#difference-with-dask-compute)).

Either way, you'll want to rewrite that has

```
from dask import compute

u, s, v = compute(u, s, v)
```

In which case all the intermediate values will be shared.

See http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/scheduler-overview.html#the-compute-function for more.